# Graph plotting library

Tags: python, plot, graph

I need a suggestion of a library that will build weighted graphs and I need an ability to display exact weight for a tree edge, that is not supported in networkx and plotly.

Answer (score 0):

Try graphviz: https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html
You can add labels to each edge, in your case weights.